# Is this "Homology" useful to study?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, homology

In the  usual  singular  homology  of  a  topological  space $X$, one consider the  free abelian group generated by  all continuous maps from the  standard simplex $\Delta^{n}$ to $X$.

Now  we  can replace  $\Delta^{n}$  by the orthonormal group $O(n)$.
There are $n+1$  (both topological and group theoretical) obvious  embedding $\epsilon_{i}:O(n)\to O(n+1),\;\;i=1,2,\ldots,n+1$. These obvious embeddings are as  follows:

$$\epsilon_{1}(A)=1 \oplus A,\;\;\\ \epsilon_{i}(A)=\lambda_{i}\epsilon_{1}(A)\lambda_{i}^{-1}$$  where  $\lambda_{i}$  is  the elementary  matrix obtaining from the  identity   matrix  by  replacing    first row  by  $i_{th}$ row.

For example,  for $n=2$, the  matrix $\epsilon_{i} \left (\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}  \right)$  is $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&a&b\\0&c&d \end{pmatrix}$,   $\begin{pmatrix}a&0&b\\0&1&0\\c&0&d \end{pmatrix}$  and $\begin{pmatrix} a&b&0\\c&d&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$,  for $i=1,2,3,\;$ respectively.

For  a  topological  space  $X$,  one  can define  $\overline{C_{n}(X)}$ as the  free  abelian  group generated  by all continuous  maps  from $O(n)$  to $X$.

The  boundary  maps  $\delta: \overline{C_{n}(X)} \to \overline{C_{n-1}(X)}$ is defined by $\delta(\phi)=\sum (-1)^i \phi \circ \epsilon_i$. Then we  have  $\delta \circ \delta =0$.

So we obtain  a kind of  "homology" as  a  functor on the category of  topological spaces. Of  course homeomorphic spaces have  isomorphic homology.

(However this  functor is  not  necessarily a homotopoic invariant functor  but it impose  an equivalent relation on the  space  of  all continuous  maps $f,g:X\to Y:\; f\simeq g$  iff $f_{*}=g_{*}$.

> Is this equivalent relation, stronger than the homotopy equivalent?

On the  other  hand, for  a  group $G$,   one  can define  the  free abelian group generated by all group homomorphism from $O(n)$  to  $G$. The  same  processes as above, gives  us a homology of groups.

> Are these type of  homologies studied  already?

Comment: Why is $d \circ d = 0$?

Comment: @RyanBudney  The reason is similar to the singular homology case. Please write it for n=2, or 3. Then you would be convinced that it works for arbitrary n.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what the "obvious" boundary maps are.   Are they precomposition with your inclusions?  There is no canonical inclusion and your objects are not defined to be homotopy-classes of maps, so it is unclear how $d$ is defined.

Comment: @RyanBudney  I defined it at this  revised version. i change  d to $\delta$, too.

Comment: I imagine these are studied, although I can't give you a reference.  Perhaps start with a book like May's Simplicial Objects in Algebraic Topology?

Comment: For the space $\mathrm{Map}(O(n),X)$ you consider the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module generated by this space, say $\mathbb{Z}\{\mathrm{Map}(O(n),X)\}$. If instead you were asking about $\mathrm{Map}(X,O(n))$ then I think the question could be related to $KO$ of $\Sigma X$ if $X$ was paracompact, after passing to homotopy of course! So, something like a free resolution of the $KO(X)$ might appear somewhere; this is just a very vague guess to the ``mirror''  of the construction you suggest!!! But, I am not sure such an example has been studied in May's book.

Comment: @user51223  Thank  you very  much for your useful  comment. As you said the space $Map(X,O(n)$ is completly different. If I am not  mistaken the spectrum of the K theory is the space of fredholm operators on a  Hilbert space. That is Vect(X) correspond to the homotopy class of  maps from X to Fred(H).

Comment: To answer your first quest, "is it useful". Probably not. I'd question its computability for even simple spaces.

Comment: My first guess is this is singular cohomology with a funny coefficient group. The coefficient group would have something to do with the bundle structure $O_n \to O_{n+1} \to S^n$.   In the $n=1$ case this is a trivial bundle so I believe you get $H^0(X; \mathbb Z^2)$, for your object derived from maps $O_1 \to X$.